# Hiding description field with Dexterity

Tags: plone, dexterity

I am using a content type which uses IBasic behavior (title + description). I'd like to hide description field on add and edit forms.

I am familiar how to do with Archetypes, but couldn't find a good way to do with Dexterity after trial-end-error - I think IBasic behavior also provides some rename-after-creation etc. logic which is also needed for my use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to hide the description field, you should not use IBasic (nor IDublinCore, as that is IBasic plus a few more).

You can define your own behavior with a title field (and possibly still a description field that you hide in the normal way with form.omitted('description') if you only want to hide it instead of complete removing it).

For the rename-after-creation part: this is the plone.app.content.interfaces.INameFromTitle behavior.  It only needs a title field, so an own behavior with just a title field would be enough.  Some more hints for this part are here: http://davidjb.com/blog/2010/04/plone-and-dexterity-working-with-computed-fields